JS8Call sound input errors when using USB as DATA MOD setting, but not when using ACC as DATA MOD setting for Icom IC-7300
I recently purchased an IC-7300 shortly after receiving my general license.
In trying out JS8Call, I discovered that when setting the radio to data mode, and ensuring the input is set to USB, I receive the below errors when trying to transmit:

JS8Call will then need to be restarted in order to work properly again, and in some instances the radio also gets stuck in transmit mode until I press the transmit button to switch back to RX.
In troubleshooting I found that if I turn off data mode, JS8Call is able to work seemingly without any issues. Further, I changed the DATA MOD setting to ACC from USB and after that JS8Call worked without any noticeable problems.
I am not sure why setting DATA MOD to "USB" is producing these issues, I have set up every other setting to the example given on JS8Call's website for the IC-7300.
Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Define "worked without any noticeable problems". Did you make any contacts that way? Did you watch the power meter while sending a message? I suspect an RFI issue, and I suspect that with DATA MOD ACC you aren't actually transmitting anything (or nothing but a small amount of noise).

@hobbs-KC2G I received SNR reports back on JS8Call, all very low (-10 to -15). I did notice a very small signature on the waterfall while transmitting, I assumed that was just how JS8Call traffic appeared when transmitting, but I see how that could be the small amount of noise you mentioned. The data cable I am using has a small ferrite choke on either end of the cable, do you propose I add another?
